# Android SQLite Alternative to offset

Tags: android, sqlite, limit

Is there any way to offset data starting from the bottom of the data?

Offset happens where it removes the first data on top, but could it possible to remove data starting from the bottom.

I tried limit, but it deleted my first few latest records.

[image]

I wanted to get the latest record and omit the old records. Actually I wanted to do a listview where it display the top 3 latest records.

[image]

And when the user click the load more button, the other messages will appear. But when a new message appear, the top 3 messages will not be replaced by the new records, instead display the top 3 messages + new records until the user click refresh and the record will query the latest top 3 records.

Thank you.

Comment: you can sort the data into descending order and offset them

Comment: @cwfei, 

Hi. I tried, but it deleted my first few latest records. 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/EU38T.png

I wanted to get the latest record and omit the old records. Actually I wanted to do a listview where it display the top 3 latest records. And when the user click the load more button, the other messages will appear. But when a new message appear, the top 3 messages will not be replaced by the new records, instead display the top 3 messages + new records until the user click refresh and the record will query the latest top 3 records.

Comment: Show your database structure, and what "latest" means in terms of that structure.

Comment: @CL. 

This is the brief structure of the database:
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/LvDr4.png

The latest 3 refers to the message with ID - 10, 9, and 8. I want to remove messages with ID 7, 6, and 5.

Thus, when a new message comes in, it becomes 11. The listview will display the messages with ID 11, 10, 9, and 8. Until when the adapter restarts, it will query the top 3 messages with ID 11, 9, and 8.

Comment: This information belongs into the question.

Comment: You said below that your IDs are strings, but you're showing numbers. Which information is correct?

Comment: @CL. The IDs in the real database are a random generated strings. The IDs in the pictures are just for illustration. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Well, neither the ID nor the timestamp are in a format that allows easy sorting. Your problem is unsolvable without changing the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I understand your question correctly.  You can first sort your table in a descending manner, and then you can use the "limit (offset), (count)" term.  For example the below SQL command will return the last 3 rows and offset or skip the very last row.

```
select * from books order by id desc limit 1, 3;
```

Comment: Hi. I tried, but it deleted my first few latest records. 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/EU38T.png

I wanted to get the latest record and omit the old records. Actually I wanted to do a listview where it display the top 3 latest records. And when the user click the load more button, the other messages will appear. But when a new message appear, the top 3 messages will not be replaced by the new records, instead display the top 3 messages + new records until the user click refresh and the record will query the latest top 3 records.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ejaski has got it right.

What you can do is. assuming you want to is "on every time user clicks load more 'n' more records show up"
like there were 3 records,
user clicked load more
3 old records + 2 new
so what you can do is.

```
offset = 1;
count = 3;
sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from books order by id desc limit ?, ?;", [offset,count]);
//When User Clicks Load more
count += 3; //say you want to load 3 more records.
//Then Execute the datafetching module and populate the list
```

Comment: Hi @Mubashir Hanif.

Thank you for your answer. Initially I did this query but when a new message comes in, it replaces my top 3 messages. For example, I have 5 messages. I select limit it to 3 so it displayed messages 5, 4, 3. When a new message comes in, it becomes 6. So it replaced to 6, 5, 4 but deletes my 3. Actually I wanted to display the new messages + top 3 old messages which are 6, 5, 4, 3. Until when the user reloads the page than it displayed the latest top 3 messages which are 6, 5, and 4. 

Thank you. :-)

Comment: The new messages you are talking about what is the strategy of getting them.. Like how do you know if a new message has came? what you can do is.. if you timely checking for new records in data base. you can execute a query to retrieve only those records who have an ID greater then what you currently have on the screen and push them into the ArrayList and update your list view.

Comment: I have attached a listener and when the new data comes, it will re-query the database. My ID are strings so I can't compare them with the previous IDs.

Comment: these string IDs are same as the ones in the database right? if yes you can easily compare them. If they can be sorted they can be compared as well.

Comment: The IDs in the real database are a random generated strings. The IDs in the pictures are just for illustration. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. The idea I get is to remove the messages below my limit in the query.